# How can I get nested json array data with varying key names and content inside?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I have a json array I am trying to get data out of. Here is what I am looking at currently:

[image: the data I am looking at]

I have below the jquery/javascript I used to generate this and give me this data that I can play with and the important part here is the `nodes` object below, this is what gets the different layouts:

```
var getPosts = function() {

        $.ajax({
          url: '/wp-json/posts?type=case-studies',
          data: {
            filter: {
            'name': _last
            }
          },
          success: function ( dataS ) {
            //List some global variables here to fetch post data
            // We use base as our global object to find resources we need
            var base = dataS[0];
            console.log(base);
            var postContent = base.content;
            var postTitle = base.title;
            // Main Image ACF object
            var featuredImage = base.meta.main_image;
            // Gallery ACF object
            var nodes = base.meta.work_content;
            // Simple ACF object
            //var textArea = base.meta.work_content[1];
            var items = [];
            for(var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++)
            {
                var layout = nodes[i];
                var layoutNames = layout.acf_fc_layout;
                items.push( layout.acf_fc_layout['gallery']);
                console.log(layout);
            };
            $('<div>', {
                "class":'loaded',
                html:items.join('')
              }).appendTo(projectContainer);
          },
          cache: false
        });

    };
```

** edited here with json itself **

The json file [here](https://gist.github.com/mdunbavan/887b77e653215be17653)

The order these items comes in is very important and it cannot be manipulated and what I need to do is get each object and append into a container with each object using a different markup layout.

Each object has `acf_fc_layout` as its key that is different, my question is how can I differentiate the different data I get with that key and offer different markup for each one? I know that some will need further loops created to get images etc and I can do that. **The other important thing to remember here is that there will be multiple of the same `acf_fc_layout` items but with different content inside them.**

Cheers

Comment: can you provide json so i will manipulate according to it

Comment: edit above @KevalBhatt

Comment: manipulate means depending upon json i will create loop for appending your variable. :D

Comment: use Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj) to get key names.

Comment: step 1) loop each data and get unique key name acf_fc_layout step 2) make loop for each unique key name get and make relate check perform and diasply content.

Comment: {"type" :"test1", "catagory"  : test 2 ,"type" : "test3"}..First get unique key names in an array as ["type","catagory"] and loop on this key...

Comment: @ParthTrivedi can you put this in a better format? Sorry its a bit confusing

Comment: @KevalBhatt that edit should show you the json output :)

Answer (score 1):

```
var items = [];
var layoutNames = [];
            for(var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++)
            {
                var layout = nodes[i];
                layoutNames.push(layout.acf_fc_layout);
                console.log(layout);
            };
//now loop on each layoutNames 
$(layoutNames).each(function (){
     for(var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++)
            {                
                var layout = nodes[i];
                if(layout.acf_fc_layout==$(this).val())
                //Perform Operation either image / video / page layout
                console.log(layout);
            };
})
```

Comment: so to access the layouts and put them into the body I would use:
`if( layout.acf_fc_layout==$(this).val() ){ //do something } else { }`? Would this still respect the order they came in when added into the backend?

Comment: As you want to use different markup for different data then this is the way.

Comment: Check if (acf_fc_layout =="gallery") then use img tag else if (acf_fc_layout =="content_area") then <p> tag..as for all the cases.

Comment: Will this affect the order they first came in though?

Comment: No. if you want to make order as it is then first make loop on nodes and then in inner loop for layoutNames.

Comment: And also will it enable me to add multiples of the same thing like 2 gallery objects, 3 content areas and 1 video?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81278/discussion-between-m-dunbavan-and-parth-trivedi).

Comment: if First loop for images then all the images in nodes get appended then second element is video then all nodes having video getting appended.

Comment: This did not work in the end :( there was a problem with loop the `layout.acf_fc_layout==$(this).val()` did not return anything